# Use variable value as x:Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button called `myBtn`. in XAML: ( `<Button x:Name="myBtn" ...` )

I have also a variable, which value is `myBtn`

Now, I need change this button's color:

```
public string buttonName = "myBtn";

private void method () 
{
     this.buttonName.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255));
}
```

This gives error:

> string does not contain definition for Background

What is right syntax to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Button buttonName;

private void method ()
{
   buttonName = this.FindName("myBtn") as Button;
   buttonName.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myBtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255));
```

Once you give the control the `x:Name` attribute, you can refer to it directly from code behind without doing anything else.

Comment: I need use variable, without directly using object  name

Comment: @OTARIKI What are you doing that requires that?

Comment: Like @E. Moffat mentioned, the name you give it in XAML becomes the variable that you can use to refer to the control in .cs files. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: See @user2946329 solution for an alternative method using FindName()

Comment: @ juharr - lets say I have 3 button, called "btn1" , "btn2" and "colorChanger", when I click on "btn1" or "btn2" ,I need 'save' this button name somewhere, and then, on "colorChanger" click, change selected ("btn1" or "btn2") button color

Answer (score 2):

You can access the background color of a named XAML button by using

```
myBtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 255));
```

The name you specify becomes a Button object for the code-behind in the application you are building.